# Mongo DB with grafana False QUERY ,new Date()

Tags: mongodb, date, new-operator, grafana

I use Grafana for monitoring.
But my query isnot working.

İn my query, ı use new Date() function, for find current date.
its working mongo shell But new Date() is not working on grafana.

Grafana doesnt accept functions on grafana command line , for example new ISODate(),new Date()  etc.

***grafana ERROR : "message " : unexpected token e in JSON position 168***

```js
{ "$year":  new Date() }       //not working

{ "$year": {"$dateFromString":{"dateString":"2018-09-08T12:10:40.787"}} }    //working
```

why could it be ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is not working"? I might be blind but both lines look exactly the same to me

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all information. Additionally, is there any error message you could share with us?